# What do -- classes mean in SASS / CSS?

Tags: css, sass, coding-style, less

I have seen people use -- signs quite a bit, if I remember correctly in use cases like these:

```
.myclass {
  //some stuff

  .--large {
    //other stuff
  }

}
```

Is this just a naming convention for an extension of a parent, or is there anything SASS / CSS specific to it? Or is my example maybe off? I am not sure I remember correctly, but I couldn't find anything on the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a BEM modifier naming convention. You can read about it here:

http://getbem.com/naming/

Comment: Thank you, that's all I needed to know! :)